# MySQL query to get row count when no data available, skip result when add where clause

Tags: mysql, database

My following query showing data count even when there is no data for that date.

```
SELECT c.date AS DATE,  COUNT(s.insertTime) AS tot_cnt   FROM (SELECT ADDDATE('1970-01-01',t4.i*10000 + t3.i*1000 + t2.i*100 + t1.i*10 + t0.i) 
DATE FROM (SELECT 0 i UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9) t0,
(SELECT 0 i UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9) t1,
(SELECT 0 i UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9) t2,
(SELECT 0 i UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9) t3,
(SELECT 0 i UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9) t4 ) c 
LEFT  JOIN `access_log` s  ON c.date = DATE(s.insertTime) 
WHERE  UNIX_TIMESTAMP(c.date)  BETWEEN 1563733801 AND 1564338599 GROUP BY c.date ORDER BY c.date;
```

But when I add userId=8, it skips all date range which don't have any value

```
SELECT c.date AS DATE,  COUNT(s.insertTime) AS tot_cnt   FROM (SELECT ADDDATE('1970-01-01',t4.i*10000 + t3.i*1000 + t2.i*100 + t1.i*10 + t0.i) 
DATE FROM (SELECT 0 i UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9) t0,
(SELECT 0 i UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9) t1,
(SELECT 0 i UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9) t2,
(SELECT 0 i UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9) t3,
(SELECT 0 i UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9) t4 ) c 
LEFT  JOIN `access_log` s  ON c.date = DATE(s.insertTime) 
WHERE  UNIX_TIMESTAMP(c.date)  BETWEEN 1563733801 AND 1564338599 AND userId=8 GROUP BY c.date ORDER BY c.date;
```

I need all date even they don't have value and also when apply userId=8 to filter records.

Comment: Is user 8 on the LEFT JOINed table? If so, move it to the JOIN

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apply the condition in the `ON` clause and not the `WHERE` clause:

```
ON c.date = DATE(s.insertTime) AND userId=8
```

so the `LEFT JOIN` returns the non matching rows.